# Can't figure out formula for Microsoft Excel 10

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Cells D2:J2 all have the capability to have a number from 6-10 in .5 increments. I need cell K2 to tell me if any of the cells in D2:J2 have a difference of 1.5 or more. If there is a difference of 1.5 or more, the cell should state SPLIT. If it is 1.4 or less, the cell should remain blank. Can anyone help me?

[image: SNIP of excel sheet]

Comment: Isn't it true to say that if the max of the range minus the minimum of the range is greater than 1.5, then it must be split?  Or is it only adjacent cells that should be compared?

Comment: Your example shows both rows as blank in the split column.  Is that because you are only concerned with adjacent values, or the example just shows the layout?

Comment: The split column is currently blank. Basically C2:J2 are board member scores. If any two board members have a score that has a difference of 1.5 or greater points, then they need to go re-score again. The term "SPLIT" is just a term we use in the scoring process, nothing to do with excel in this instance. K2 is only concerned with the data in C2 - J2. It's empty because I can't figure out a formula

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=IF(MAX(D2:J2)-MIN(D2:J2)>=1.5,"SPLIT","")
```